# New customized column not performing search operation in SOLine InventoryID field selector in Acumatica

Tags: .net, acumatica, acumatica-kb

We have overridden and added new column in SOLine InventoryID selector field, but search operation is not working on the newly added column.

We have tried by adding FastFilterFields property for the Document Details Grid, but still no luck.

Can anyone provide a solution on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the new field of type PXDBString or PXString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on this requirement and please find the code snippet below to perform the search operation on a customized column for SOLine InventoryID field in the Sales Order screen.

Add Grid Properties with FastFilterfiles to the SegmentedMask like below

```
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%"
                    TabIndex="100" SkinID="DetailsInTab" StatusField="Availability" SyncPosition="True" Height="473px">
                    <Levels>
                        <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Transactions">
                            <RowTemplate>
                                <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="S" ControlSize="SM"></px:PXLayoutRule>
                                <px:PXSegmentMask AutoRefresh="true" CommitChanges="True" ID="edInventoryID" runat="server" DataField="InventoryID" AllowEdit="True">
                                    <GridProperties FastFilterFields="UsrKNAMIBotonicalName"></GridProperties>
                                </px:PXSegmentMask>
```

[image: InventoryID Field Selector]

I hope I have answered your question. Thanks !!