# Search using 2 fields in Custom PXSelector Control

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a Custom PXSelector Control built using the code below

```
using PX.Data.ReferentialIntegrity.Attributes;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.Common.Discount.Attributes;
using PX.Objects.Common.Discount;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.DR;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.FA;
using PX.Objects.GL.DAC.Abstract;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using PX.Objects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTran>
  {
    #region UsrResource
    [PXDBString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Resource",Required = true)]
    [PXSelector(
          typeof(Search<CSAttributeDetail.valueID,Where<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID, Equal<AttributeExtender.resource>>>),
          typeof(CSAttributeDetail.valueID),
          typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description),
          SubstituteKey = typeof(CSAttributeDetail.valueID)
    )]

    public virtual string UsrResource { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrResource : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrResource> { }
    #endregion
  }
     public static class AttributeExtender
  {
    public const string Resource = "RESOURCE";
    public class resource : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<resource>
    {
       public resource() : base(Resource) {; }
    }
                               
  } 
}
```

The challenge is when the user is searching for a Resource in the Control, The search is only filtering using the first column (valueID) as shown in the picture here
[image: Custom PXSelector searching using first column only]

A standard PXSelector Control searches across all columns displayed by the selector as shown in the picture here
[image: Standard PXSelector searching across all columns]

My question is, **how do I enable my Custom PXSelector Control to allow user to search across all the columns it displays (valueID and description) like what the standard PXSelector Controls does so that the user can search using description column as well?**

Answer (score 0):

To perform the search operation, we need to add all the fields in FastFilterfiles in Grid Properties.

Please check this link, I hope this will help you - [New customized column not performing search operation in SOLine InventoryID field selector in Acumatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376859/new-customized-column-not-performing-search-operation-in-soline-inventoryid-fiel/60388646#60388646)